# How can I parse OPTIONAL statements from a SPARQL query using Sesame?

Tags: java, sesame

I'm playing around with Sesame's queryparser-sparql lib, but I can't seem to get `OPTIONAL` statements from a parsed query.

Given the query:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s a ex:Foo .
  OPTIONAL { ?s ex:someProperty ?property }
} LIMIT 10
```

Parsing it with the following code (using Sesame 2.7.2):

```
SPARQLParserFactory factory = new SPARQLParserFactory();
QueryParser parser = factory.getParser();
ParsedQuery parsedQuery = parser.parseQuery(sparqlQuery, null);

StatementPatternCollector collector = new StatementPatternCollector();
TupleExpr tupleExpr = parsedQuery.getTupleExpr();
tupleExpr.visit(collector);

for (StatementPattern pattern : collector.getStatementPatterns()) {
    System.out.println(pattern);
}
```

printing `parsedQuery` gives:

```
Slice ( limit=10 )
   Projection
      ProjectionElemList
         ProjectionElem "s"
         ProjectionElem "property"
      LeftJoin
         StatementPattern
            Var (name=s)
            Var (name=-const-1, value=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type, anonymous)
            Var (name=-const-2, value=http://example.com/#Foo, anonymous)
         StatementPattern
            Var (name=s)
            Var (name=-const-3, value=http://example.com/#someProperty, anonymous)
            Var (name=property)
```

printing each `pattern` gives:

```
StatementPattern
   Var (name=s)
   Var (name=-const-1, value=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type, anonymous)
   Var (name=-const-2, value=http://example.com/#Foo, anonymous)

StatementPattern
   Var (name=s)
   Var (name=-const-3, value=http://example.com/#someProperty, anonymous)
   Var (name=property)
```

How can I get information from a `StatementPattern` on whether or not it is `OPTIONAL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to figure that out is to check whether it occurs as (part of) a right-hand argument of a `LeftJoin`. A relatively simply way to figure that out is to implement a `QueryModelVisitor` that sets a flag of some sort whenever it encounters a left join and descends down its right-hand side argument.

Alternatively, you can propagate back up in the query model from the `StatementPattern` via `getParent` and inspect the tree like that - this may be more difficult though as the `LeftJoin` may not necessarily be the immediate parent of the SP.

Comment: Works like a charm, using the `QueryModelVisitorBase` I can get the information I need. Thanks!